# HAProxy is in infinite loop

Tags: docker, proxy, infinite-loop, haproxy

Following is my haproxy.cfg (in docker)

```
global
    maxconn 100
    log /sidecar/log local0
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option httpclose
    retries 5
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

frontend http-in
    bind *:443 ssl crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy/test.pem
    acl API_URL hdr_beg(host) -i simapi.mydomain.com
    use_backend API if API_URL   

    default_backend API

backend API
    mode http
    server simapi simapi.mydomain.com:443 ssl check verify none
```

Logs:...

```
logging           | Apr 24 07:25:14 d60ace4109d8 haproxy[7]: Connect from 127.0.0.1:35534 to 127.0.0.1:443 (http-in/HTTP)
logging           | Apr 24 07:25:14 d60ace4109d8 haproxy[7]: Connect from 127.0.0.1:35536 to 127.0.0.1:443 (http-in/HTTP)
logging           | Apr 24 07:25:14 d60ace4109d8 haproxy[7]: Connect from 127.0.0.1:35538 to 127.0.0.1:443 (http-in/HTTP)
logging           | Apr 24 07:25:14 d60ace4109d8 haproxy[7]: Connect from 127.0.0.1:35540 to 127.0.0.1:443 (http-in/HTTP)
logging           | Apr 24 07:25:14 d60ace4109d8 haproxy[7]: Connect from 127.0.0.1:35542 to 127.0.0.1:443 (http-in/HTTP)
logging           | Apr 24 07:25:14 d60ace4109d8 haproxy[7]: Connect from 127.0.0.1:35544 to 127.0.0.1:443 (http-in/HTTP)
logging           | Apr 24 07:25:14 d60ace4109d8 haproxy[7]: Connect from 127.0.0.1:35546 to 127.0.0.1:443 (http-in/HTTP)
logging           | Apr 24 07:25:25 d60ace4109d8 haproxy[7]: Server API/simapi is DOWN, reason: Layer6 timeout, check duration: 2002ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 100 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
logging           | Apr 24 07:25:25 d60ace4109d8 haproxy[7]: backend API has no server available!
```

It seems like going into loop when request to `https://simapp.mydomain.com`.

SSL seems to be ok as it gives warning in browser and I bypass it (as you do in dev certificate).

Any idea?

Comment: You seems to be listening and then routing traffic to the same interface. So it will go on a loop. what were you expecting ?

Comment: @MoEmEn sorry but I am new to haproxy. My intention is when user hits https://simapi.mydomain.com the request should hit haproxy server first and the haproxy server should route it to simapi server.

Comment: It looks like the  simapi.mydomain.com:443 is pointing to the haproxy server and not the simapi one